# Gmail says `This message seems dangerous` on emails sent by my web store

Tags: gmail

Gmail shows a red banner above email messages sent by my web store.

> `This message seems dangerous`
>
> Many people marked similar messages as phishing scams, so this might contain unsafe content. Avoid clicking links, downloading attachments or replying with personal information.

I just registered a new domain on `.software` domain and using AWS SES for dispatching email. Before I sent same emails from `.com` domails and it was fine.

What can I do to whitelist my domain?

'DKIM', `_dmarc.` , `v=spf1 include:` are set.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

This is how it was before, screenshot is taken from gmail:

[image]

You see, mailed by was a default amazon service instead of my custom `.software` domain.

MAIL FROM Domain can be set on SES, it is not new.

But my problem was that I had not only domains registered, but also email addresses in my `Identity management`, and when you register your email address separate from your domain you need to specify `MAIL FROM Domain` on your email address again.

`Mail from domain` that is set for Email address has a higher priority than a `Mail from domain`  that is set for entire domain.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is the sender domain or the IP. The issue can be the content as well. Google will only show this when their system has reported people clicking on the "phishing" option. In your case, I assume its the .software domain, coz this tents to show that there is a zip or attached software, or clicked to a software that downloads, and might contain malware.

Comment: This doesn't address the OP's question. They specifically said that it's for their domain. The solution that they posted is correct